# Deterrent effect of nuclear weapons in comparison with carrying Firearms?

Tags: logic, ethics, social-ethics, politics, freedom

Would it be feasible to to compare the deterrent effect of nuclear weapons between nuclear armed countries (if such exist),
with the deterrent effect of a majority of citizen carrying firearms, inside a country (if such exist).

Especially under the aspect of keeping the peace by equalizing power.
And under the aspect that a total disarmament in both cases would be impossible

Comment: Why would you compare deterrent effect on a single person in a country to deterrent effect on an entire country as a whole (or more precisely, on its government)? It sounds like apples and oranges. And deterrence of what in case of the firearms? Murders?

Comment: South Africa unilaterally disarmed. Many countries multilaterally reduced stocks. A wide range of constraints have been accepted by the weapons holding world. The 'success' of MAD hides how close we came to apocalypse, for stupid reasons https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_close_calls During the Cuban missile crisis Castro advocated nuclear 1st strike against USA despite the costs to Cuba, as described in The Fog Of War film. No rational person aware of history could advocate for the current nuclear staus quo.

Comment: No rational person can advocate for current US weapon laws either, which stand in oppositiin to public opinion https://www.ft.com/content/ec6ad756-a915-11e7-93c5-648314d2c72c The real reason for the fervor around that issue, is that many people there don't trust their government, and those same people think hand guns can guarantee their liberties. But https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DK6IGG5zRU8 Between suicide, domestic abuse, and accidents, guns are far more likely to kill their owners than defend them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison is as feasible as comparing the budgetary policies of a nation to that of a household, or the governing policies of a nation to that of a household.

That is to say, not very.  Historically these comparisons fall short because the environment a government operates in is *very* different from the environment of an individual.  In my own informal studies, I have found people have a *very* difficult time intuiting on government scale numbers or government levels of sovereignty.  They're just too far removed from individual levels.